# Receiving CORS policy error when submitting form from Angular to flask application

Tags: flask, cors, flask-cors

I have tried several things but I am not able to figure this one out. I have a back-end flask app and a front-end client written in Angular. When I submit my register user form I get a cors error. I have read the documentation for `flask_cors` and have tried to get it to work but I still get the same error below:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Here is my `app.py` from the flask app.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import os, sys
from flask import Flask
import pathlib
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

import coloredlogs, logging as log
coloredlogs.install()

from main.apis.user import api as User
from main.apis.auth import api as Auth

from main import create_app
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

# Init app
app = Flask(__name__)

#cors = CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})

CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:4200", allow_headers=[
    "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
    supports_credentials=True, intercept_exceptions=False)

authorizations = {
    'token': {
        'type': 'apiKey',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    }
}

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
app = create_app(config_name)


api = Api(app, authorizations=authorizations, version='1.0', title='API docs',
    description='A simple REST API with JWT authentication.',
    doc='/docs'
)

app.config['jwt']._set_error_handler_callbacks(api)
app.config['ROOT_DIR'] = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()


# @app.before_first_request
# this function is to init the db and realted models
# def create_tables():
    # print("Before first statement")
#     db.create_all()


# Endpoints
api.add_namespace(Auth, path='/v1')
api.add_namespace(User, path='/v1')

# Run Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this seemed to fix my issue.

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your code you are creating `app = Flask(__name__)`, applying the `CORS` to that variable and then over writing `app` by using `app = create_app(config_name)` a few lines later.  So that causes your `CORS` setup on the first `app` to be lost.